# Task could not find "AL.exe" using the SdkToolsPath

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I have this problem tring to build one solution

Task could not find "AL.exe" using the SdkToolsPath "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\" or the registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A". Make sure the SdkToolsPath is set and the tool exists in the correct processor specific location under the SdkToolsPath and that the Microsoft Windows SDK is installed

I know there is a similar question, but the aswer didn't work for me

In the same computer a can build other solutions in Net 4 without any problem, so don't understand

I'm using:
Windows XP Professional SP3
Visual Web Developer 2010 Express

Comment: Odds are pretty good that this is not included with the Express edition, it certainly isn't an Express kind of tool.  You'll need to install the full version of the SDK.

Comment: I installed Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1...but didn't work

Answer (score 17):

Easiest thing to do is copy **al.exe**
from
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\
(For Windows 10 from
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6 Tools)

to
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\

Comment: Can you suggest target location for Windows server 2012

Comment: It's probably healtier to install target framework version tools via visual studio installer. 
Creating a folder with different version can cause other issues in the future.

Answer (score 10):

As I got this issue in VS2019 after a fresh install of both Windows and Visual Studio 2019 I thought it might be good to share:

**Installing Microsoft.Net.Component.4.7.2.SDK from the Visual Studio installer fixed it for me!**

Comment: This advice helped, except I installed 4.6.1 and 4.7.2 in addition to 4.8 which was there. That's because I have VS solutions with projects targeting all of these versions.

Comment: Thank you.  You saved my day. I had this issue with Xamarin Forms project.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have any resource files in your project? Try to delete all of them and build your project again.
I've got exact the same error and after deleting the resource files (*.hrsx) my build worked again.

Maybe it helps.

Comment: thanks for the advice...I install vs 2010 professional and the problem is resolved

Comment: @Mariusz it worked for me, but do you know why is that errir popping only when adding resource files

Answer (score 2):

I am using VS2019, this way works for me:

Add a system env variable `TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory`

like this:
`TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.2 Tools`