# Visual studio 2013 Build error on TFS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, tfs, msbuild

I use framework 4.5 and vs 2013 and TFS 2013. When I build project get error like that;

> "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets
>   (3079): Task could not find "AL.exe" using the SdkToolsPath "" or the
>   registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x86". Make sure the
>   SdkToolsPath is set and the tool exists in the correct processor
>   specific location under the SdkToolsPath and that the Microsoft
>   Windows SDK is installed"

I tried everything but I could't fix error. Can you help me about it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Task could not find "AL.exe" using the SdkToolsPath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923131/task-could-not-find-al-exe-using-the-sdktoolspath)

Comment: Do you have windows sdk 8.1 installed?

Comment: @Isantipov yes i already installed sdk 8.1

Comment: @thumbmunkeys i tried it but didn't work

Comment: @thumbmunkeys , did you try to put a correct path into HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x86 ?

Comment: @Isantipov I'm trying

Comment: @Isantipov I checked but didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Download and install the [Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 8.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bg162891.aspx). In the setup program, make sure **.NET Framework 4.5.1 Software Development Kit** is selected.

This will install al.exe to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools.