# TFS Build Fails - Task could not find "AL.exe" using the SdkToolsPath

Tags: continuous-integration, tfsbuild, tfs-2015, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

My TFS Build task in Windows Server 2012 R2 fails throwing the error as stated below

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (2863, 5)
>   Task could not find "AL.exe" using the SdkToolsPath "" or the registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x86". Make sure the SdkToolsPath is set and the tool exists in the correct processor specific location under the SdkToolsPath and that the Microsoft Windows SDK is installed

Copied AL.exe from different location and pasted in C:\Program Files (x86)... as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923131/task-could-not-find-al-exe-using-the-sdktoolspath) but it didn't solve my issue.

Comment: Did you try this - Installing SDK    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986440/msbuild-on-ci-server-cant-find-al-exe

Comment: No..Let me try and update

Comment: I've installed SDK from here but still i dont see - WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x86 in Registry    
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34860

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the Windows [SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34860) from Microsoft site and/or configure RegEdit. This should work

Answer (score 0):

For anyone out there, if you ware trying to update your Visual Studio Build Tools to newer version, make sure that "Build" task in tfs finds proper MSBuild folder- if agent that runs the build is old, it might not find new Visual Studio Build Tools. I just changed method of locating MSBuild from "Specyfic Version" to "Specyfic Path" in "Build" and pointed to new VS Build Tools